# I need to convert C code block, which calculate checksum to Java code. I have no idea how to do this (

Tags: java, c, checksum

I have an electronic board on which I am printing the data. To calculate the checksum byte of output are using the following algorithm:

```
word CountCS(byte *Buff, byte Cnt) //Cnt - count of bytes
{
  dword cs1, cs2, m;
  byte k;
  k=0;
  cs1=0;
  cs2=0;
  while (Cnt) {
    m=*Buff;
    cs1 +=m;
    m ^=0x5A;
    if (k) m=(m >> k) | (m << (8-k));
    k=(k+1) & 0x07;
    cs2 +=m;
    Buff++;
    Cnt--;
  };
  return (cs2<<8) | (cs1 & 0xFF);
}
```

The manufacturer of scoreboard provide code in C, I need to convert it to java. I've try to convert, but result is wrong, here java code

```
   public int checksum(int [] buffer, int count) {
    int cs1 =0, cs2 = 0, m;
    int k = 0, i = 0;
    while (count != 0) {
        m = buffer[i];
        cs1 += m;
        m ^= 0x5a;
        if (k != 0) m = (m >> k) | (m << (8-k));
        k = (k +1) & 0x07;
        cs2 += m;
        i++;
        count--;
    }
    return (cs2 << 8) | (cs1 & 0xff);
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
Just sorry, but I'm new to java.

Thanks a lot, problem is solved

Comment: And the *question* is....?

Comment: This is a trivial task for anybody who knows basics of C and java. What did you expect, that we teach you from the beginning?

Comment: A word is 16 bits, so you may want to return a short.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (k) m=(m >> k) | (m << (8-k));
```

should be

```
if (k != 0) m = (m >> k) | (m << (8-k));
```

not

```
if (k == 0) m = (m >> k) | (m << (8-k));
```

Comment: lesson learned? implicit conversion from integer to bool in C is prone to misinterpretation?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable sizes are different: k (byte vs int).  In java int is 32 bit signed.  byte in C++ may be dependent on platform, more likely 8 or 16 bits unsigned. So it would have different values as you add and multiply/shift, etc.